# Exact online - bad request 400

Tags: exact-online

Im trying to call the api but I get the bad reuqest 400 response.

accoring to documenation this could be because of syntax error:

> This error occurs when the request could not be understood by the
> server due to malformed syntax. The client should not repeat the
> request without modifications.

My endpoint

`"https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/850750/read/financial/AgingOverview?$select=AgeGroup,AgeGroupDescription,AmountPayable,AmountReceivable,CurrencyCode",`

`"https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/850750/read/financial/AgingOverviewByAccount?$select=AgeGroup,AgeGroupDescription,AmountPayable,AmountReceivable,CurrencyCode",`

First endpoint works, second throws the syntrax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the AgingOverviewByAccount, without supplying an account ID. The AgingOverview endpoint gets an overview of your suppliers/customers.

See: https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=ReadFinancialAgingOverview

The AgingOverviewByAccount does this but for specific account. Therefore, you need to supply the endpoint with an accountID as such:

```
/api/v1/{division}/read/financial/AgingOverviewByAccount?accountId=guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'&$select=AgeGroup,AgeGroupDescription,AmountPayable,AmountReceivable,CurrencyCode
```

And a bad request error is thrown when you don't supply an accountId, as the server does not know from what account you are requesting the Aging Overview.